# Troubleshooting Azure Redis Cache size spikes?

Tags: azure, caching, redis

My azure redis cache management page every now and then reports crazy-high spikes in memory consumption, take a look:
[image]

As you can see, out of basically nowhere, memory usage almost triples.
I would like to know if there's a way to hook an alert or something and log data such as "Present Keys", their respective size, Time-To-Live and others?
This can be done either on a regular basis, but i would prefer only when memory goes above a certain threshold...

Comment: What is happening with your key count for this same time window?  Is it also going up?

Comment: @JonCole actually no... key count raised, but very slightly... like 100 new keys or less...